# Auto Increment HexValue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to set auto increment hex value in SQL server or MySQL server without using primary key and varbinary ? I have tried it using trigger by converting primary key into hex value.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT( VARBINARY(8), 100)

Answer (score 0):

NEWSEQUENTIALID() can be used which is not sequential but unique

```
col uniqueidentifier default NEWSEQUENTIALID()
```